# PDO to connect to web sql from localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, connection

I am trying to do some testing, i am using MAMP and trying to connect to my SQL database on my server. I haven't used PDO before and am having a hard time tracking down what error codes mean what. I am getting this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname' (60)
```

My connection function:

```
  function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="hostname";
    $dbuser="user";
    $dbpass="password";
    $dbname="somedb";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
  }
```

where i am trying to perform the query:

```
  function getTypes() {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM type";
    try {
      $db = getConnection();
      $stmt = $db->query($sql);
      $types = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $db = null;
      echo '{"wine": ' . json_encode($types) . '}';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
    echo 'getTypes';
  }
```

**Edit:** I can connect using the same credentials with mysqli.

Comment: Could you show the code that works with _mysqli_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security problem. To avoid your database beeing flooded or filled with garbage a configuration setting says "only local ip can access to the database". All shared hosting do that and it is a good practice to do it if you have a dedicated server.

in /var/mysql/my.conf on linux you have got something like that :

```
skip-external-locking
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: so basically since i am trying to access it from localhost, and not the server that it is associated with it is locking me out? That makes sense, I can just recreate the DB in localhost

Comment: you can and it is quite logical. On localhost you are developping, online you are on production. If a developpement bug brings garbage in your database you will be quite upset.

Comment: yeah this makes sense, I was just testing retrieving data so I was just going to skip the step, but I will go ahead and do it anyways

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql server is either listening to **local unix socket** or bind to **localhost** (`127.0.0.1`). Make sure mysql server is listening on the external IP address of `hostname`.

Note: The connecting user (`user` here) must have access (`GRANT`) from your clients IP on the database (`somedb`);

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the right port?

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;port=PORT;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: how would i check what port to use? I never had to enter one with mysqli. Would it be in my settings somewhere in godaddy?

Comment: You are using godaddy shared hosting? I think then mysql server is listening in local unix socket. See my answer. You need to talk to godaddy support.

Answer (score 0):

If your server that is running the PHP scripts is the server running the SQL Server, you need to not use `hostname` a connection, you need to refer to the local system. What you have in your config, `hostname` does not resolve to an IP of a valid SQLServer, where if you reference `localhost`, it will reference the running server itself, and connect how it needs to. You can use either of the following:

`localhost` || `127.0.0.1`