# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (60)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a Web Application under PHP with a remote database, in which I have the following test script:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;dbname=db_app;', $user, $password);
    $date = ($dbh->query('SELECT NOW()');
    print_r($date);   
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
exit();
```

and when I run it I get the following output:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.16.50.87' (60)

I can still connect to the target database using MySQL workbench and through Command Line Interface.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094194/pdo-to-connect-to-web-sql-from-localhost) I get that the remote server configuration "could have been" the problem. However, we have a "brother" PHP application  connecting to the same server without problems, the only difference beetwen the two is the username and password, and even when running tests on my application using the "brother" PHP application credentials, the same error is shown. So it seems that only my PHP seems to have the problem.

I'm running tests on PHP 5.5.3 and the target server is running MySQL  5.5
Both My Application and the Brother Application are running on the Staging Server A, and both should be connecting to MySQL in Staging Server B. The Brother application is also written in PHP and is able to connect, but mine isn't. I'm guessing it could be a MySQL-relative PHP configuration.

- My application uses `PDO`, while the brother application uses
  `mysqli`.
- The brother application runs on the same server as my application,
  and connects to the same target server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You write "I can still connect to the target database using MySQL workbench and through Command Line Interface" - from the exact same system using the exact same user name & password? Trying to rule out the obvious...

Comment: *"`('SELECT NOW()') as $row)`"* --- what am I not grasping.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of both files containing the DB server credentials? Maybe your password uses some fancy non ASCII characters...

Comment: LOL fred, I'm so stressed I only half-adjusted the test code I had used in a different project.. I'll correct that. And, yes, I connect using the exact same system/username/password, the only difference is using Workbench is OK, using CLI is OK, brother application connects successfully using mysqli, but I can't connect using either PDO or mysqli

Comment: besides... MySQL uses a different error message `Access denied for user 'example'@'host (using password: YES)` when username and password combinations are wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I've read _so many_ questions lately which overlook the simple things...

Comment: @ZombieHunter The codification for the files containing database credentials are both ASCII for My Application and Brother Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it was SELinux causing the issues:

```
[root@server ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
[root@server ~]# setenforce 0
[root@server ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

[Run below as root:](http://www.filonov.com/2009/08/07/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-13/)

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Comment: I see, it's been a couple years since this issue arouse and selinux never came to my mind then, I have gotten more experience as a sysadmin and I acknowledge selinux could have been the origin of this issue.